# Python dictionary with tuple keys - access to dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary:

```
links = {   (4,32):"Link1",
            (3,32):"Link2",
            (2,32):"Link3",
            (1,32):"Link4",
            (0,32):"Link5",
            (4,64):"Link6",
            (3,64):"Link7",
            (2,64):"Link8",
            (1,64):"Link9",
            (0,64):"Link10"}
```

I would like to access to values in this dictionary giving two element of tuple.

Something like this:

```
#pseudocode

x = 0
y = 64

(x,y) ---> Link10
```

Comment: You could just do `links[(x,y)]` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
 links[(x,y)]
```

Use the tuple as key to access your dictionary